# Person field Read-Only not working in Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, jsom, list-form, browser-compatibility

I make person field as read-only in my list forms using following code.

```
$('div.ms-inputuserfield').eq(1).attr('disabled','disabled');
```

OR

```
$('div.ms-inputuserfield').eq(1).prop( "disabled", true );
```

This is working in IE. But not working in Chrome. Any reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `contentEditable` attribute to `false` to disable the field

```
$('div.ms-inputuserfield').eq(1).attr("contentEditable","false");
```

Comment: It works as expected.